# AnimatedTiledMapTile not to loop

Tags: java, dictionary, libgdx, tile, animated

I have a bullet moving, when it hits something, I want an explosion, which I have as an animated tile, to just loop once, and then replace with a default tile.

Is there any way for an AnimatedTiledMapTile not to continuously loop?

any advice on this would be good.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question specifically, can you use AnimatedTiledMapTile to do this? It doesn't look like it:

http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/maps/tiled/tiles/AnimatedTiledMapTile.html

You basically have two options. Option one: render your explosion on-top of the tile (Using a class that has extended Animation or Image for example) and replace the old tile with the new one when the explosion is happening. Or option two: extend the AnimatedTiledMapTile class and make the modifications such that you can customize the animation type like in the Animation class.

Comment: Hi,thanks for your feedback. I was hoping I was missing something with it before trying to extend the class or look for an alternative.

Comment: It's all there in the javadocs. I mean, you could check the superclass, but it doesn't look like the superclass is used for animations at all.